# Read value from pyspark column with cast

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a file with column id, earlier it used to be a small number and has datatype as int but later on had bigger values and now the values in it are of type bigint.

I am trying to read the value from the column as:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import * 
df = spark.read.parquet("hadoop file location")
df=df.selectExpr("cast(id as BIGINT) as id1") # also tried cast(id as INT) same error

df.show(10, False)
```

I am getting an exception as:

```
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SchemaColumnConvertNotSupportedException

Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecutionException: Parquet column cannot be converted in file hdfsfilename.snappy.parquet. Column: [id], Expected: int, Found: INT64
```

How can i read the correct value of column id from this data?

Comment: did you try reading parquet with `mergeSchema`? `spark.read.option("mergeSchema","true").parquet("hadoop file location")`

Comment: I tried, it says: Failed to merge incompatible data types int and bigint
@koiralo